# cannot add a service reference to Windows Phone 7.1 project (dialog not available)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I added a service reference to project A in the past.  I deleted the reference and tried to "add a service reference" by right clicking on the project, and that option is not there anymore.  Only "Add reference" is in the menu.  Same thing in the Project menu on the top.

I opened another windows phone project of mine (project B), I was able to see "add a service reference" after right clicking THAT project...

I compared cjproj files and I copied project B csproj text to project A, didn't work.

I'm mystified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to create a new windows phone project and migrating each file and folder over.  Not fun.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be [a known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558449/wp7-tools-add-service-reference-menu-missing-from-visual-studio-2010-ultimate). Try cleaning the solution and reloading it. Also, delete any service references that might be located in the project folder.

Comment: deleted a file "ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" recleaned, rebuilt, reloaded, nothing.